# Search file contents for string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to replicate the Dropbox javascript SDK filesSearch on a local directory using Node.js. I need to basically walk through the directory and search every filename, and it's contents, against a search term, and if a match(es) are found, add them to a results array that can be sorted on matches at the end.

After endlessly searching for a node module that can do this, I decided to do it myself. I've successfully got the walking through the directory down fine, and I can do a simple match on the folder name and file name, but I cannot see how to search the file contents?! The files are predominantly PDF's but may also be Word and Excel documents also.

This is my 'walking' code so far:

```
walk_through_local_repository(store.get("local_repository_path"), search_term);
var results = [];

function walk_through_local_repository(path, search_term) {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, dir) => {
        for(var i = 0; i < dir.length; ++i) {
            // ignore hidden files/folders
            if(dir[i].charAt(0) !== "." && dir[i] !== "TEMP")
            {
                // determine whether or not the item is a file or a folder
                if(fs.lstatSync(path+"/"+dir[i]).isDirectory())
                {
                    // it's a folder, check the folder name for matches
                    if(dir[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(search_term) !== -1)
                    {
                        var score = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var score = 0;
                    }

                    // go again
                    console.log("going to walk_through_local_repository again for "+path+"/"+dir[i]+".");
                    walk_through_local_repository(path+"/"+dir[i], search_term);
                }
                else if(fs.lstatSync(path+"/"+dir[i]).isFile())
                {
                    // It's a file, check the filename for matches
                    if(dir[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(search_term) !== -1)
                    {
                        var score = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var score = 0;
                    }

                    // check the file CONTENTS here and update the score for this file again
                }
                results[i] = {path:path+"/"+dir[i], score:score};
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So I have three questions really...

1. Is there a better way to do this? Have I missed a module somewhere?!
2. If not, how do I search the contents of the files? PDF's, Word docs and Excel Spreadsheets
3. How do I know when it's been through the whole directory and I can display the results array?

Comment: I think this will be quite hard with Node alone. If you know where the code will be deployed, I think it would be better to leverage what the operating system already is doing. For example on a mac you can access spotlight, which already catalogs files by content. There's a module for it too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-spotlight . Maybe there are for the OS you are using too..

Comment: Where does the code at Question read the contents of the file? Have you tried converting the `.pdf` and excel contents to plain text before searching the contents?

Comment: @Mark_M that's exactly what I need! But the vast majority of users will be on Windows machines... where would I look for that?!

Comment: @guest271314 It doesn't yet... with the different file formats I wasn't quite sure how to approach it... I had found several pdf to text node modules but without a module for each file type it's not good!

Comment: Have not tried to use an excel file in some time. Have you tried using `FileReader` to read `.pdf` files?

Comment: Are all these documents on clients machines or on a central server?

Comment: @Matt on the clients machine

Comment: @guest271314 Ooo interesting... looking at this now... it doesn't SEEM limited to just PDF's as well, which is key. If I can't do them all then there's no point doing one.

Comment: @guest271314 FileReader requires the files to be manually selected by the user for security purposes so this isn't going to be any good for my purposes I'm afraid. Thanks though.

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns `FileReader` can read any `Blob` or `File` object, not only files selected by user https://www.npmjs.com/package/filereader, see also  https://www.npmjs.com/package/screw-filereader